# Converting Cookie String to List<Cookie>

Tags: rest-api, pagereference, string

I have cookie String value returned by code below:

```
HttpResponse response = http.send(request); 
String cookieString = response.getHeader('Set-Cookie');
```

Now I am trying to construct a Pagereference object and set all above cookies to object by setCookies method. So I need to convert `cookieString` to `List<Cookie>` .Below is sample `cookieString`

```
BAh7CToPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlYzUxZjI1Mzk1OWQ0Yzk4ZWQ2MDIyYjI4NGQ1YWM4M2Y6DmltYWdlX3VybCIPb25lcGdyLnBuZzoMdXNlcl9pZGkCyQk6C2hlYWRlcmkG--991056d6df37715189eb57700524a3561a7d3126;
 domain=domain.com; path=/; HttpOnly;_shovell_session2=;
 domain=domain.com; path=/; expires=Tue, 31-May-2016 07:21:29 GMT;;
 api_userid=2505; domain=domain.com; path=/; expires=Tue, 31-May-2016 07:21:29 GMT;;
 api_sessionid=c51f253959d4c98ed6022b284d5ac83f;
 domain=domain.com; path=/; expires=Tue, 31-May-2016 07:21:29 GMT;;
 visits=1; path=/
```

Cookie object has constructor of below type

```
Cookie(name, value, path, maxAge, isSecure)
```

I can think of writing String splitting logic but that would be prone to exceptions. Is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: Nope, you will have to apply String splitting logic. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast type `String` to type `List<Cookie>`. You have to split the cookie string by `;;` and then add them to the list. If you have some problem, I can post sample code.

Comment: Yes I can write splitting logic. But In that case I am expecting cookie sting to be of same format all the time. I see possibilities of exceptions if some special character came in between or split logic didn't worked at some day.

Comment: I don't think so. Your cookies is always separeted by `;;`

Comment: The OP already said that he can manually use the string splitting logic...

Comment: please, vote my answer!